# Estrutura struct em C ser alocada de maneira dinâmica

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, alocação

Estou precisando que seja alocada de maneira dinâmica mas não estou conseguindo encontrar o problema.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define tam 10

typedef struct pilha{
    char dado[tam];
    int pos;
}Pilha;

Pilha *p=(Pilha*)malloc(sizeof(Pilha));

void push(char valor){
    p->dado[p->pos]=valor;
    p->pos++;
}

void pop(){
    p->dado[--p->pos];
}

int size(){
    return p->pos;
}

int main(){

    push("d");
    push("b");
    pop();

    printf("Tamanho da pilha é: %d",size());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Já tentou em colocar isso `Pilha *p=(Pilha*)malloc(sizeof(Pilha));` na função main? E também colocar um `ponteiro` da pilha como parâmetro das funções? Exemplo: `void push(char valor)` deixe isso assim `void push(Pilha *p, char valor)`. Faça essas alterações que vai funcionar.

Comment: Vou fazer isso, muito obrigado pela dica!